# Cloud-based node.js console app needs to run once a day

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm looking for what I would assume is quite a standard solution: I have a node app that doesn't do any web-work - simply runs and outputs to a console, and ends. I want to host it, preferably on Azure, and have it run once a day - ideally also logging output or sending me the output.

The only solution I can find is to create a VM on Azure, and set a cron job - then I need to either go fetch the debug logs daily, or write node code to email me the output. Anything more efficient available?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions would be worth investigating.  It can be timer triggered and would avoid the overhead of a VM.

Also I would investigate Azure Container Instances, this is a good match for their use case.   You can have a container image that you run on an ACI instance that has your Node app.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-deploy-app

Comment: I did a fair amount of reading - they only seem to be able to work for a Web App, not a console app?

Comment: You should be able to the Node.JS console code regardless in Functions. (assuming you don't have local file or etc. dependencies)  While Functions has a lot of web binding options in the end its just a program run on a host and should run your console code the same as it would in a VM.

Comment: Azure functions seem like they could do it, but are so clumsy and have bad documentation so far - I'm going to look into a container rather